# worksheet change two choice intersect

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use two choices for an `Intersect` in `Worksheet_Change` but the code below does not work. Nothing happens when I run the macro, even when I use `Not Intersect Is Nothing`, it still does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A100")) Then
        MsgBox "column A" & Target.Value
    End If

    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B100")) Then
        MsgBox "column B" & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you put as Target argument when you call Sub? If given range has more than 1 cell then you Exit Sub on first condition.

Comment: i am only changing a single cell inside those ranges

Comment: Sub has an argument Target. When calling it, what do you put in Target, is it single cell for sure?

Comment: @bracko it's an event handler, called when the user changes some cells on the worksheet.  Target is set by what the cells the user changes.   OP has explained they change only one cell, so Target will be a single cell.

Comment: i restarted the Excel application i found out all my macros stopped working but when i run the macro and change a cell in column A it throws a type mismatch error and when i change a cell in column B it throws a object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Change `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub`. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

**2.** Change `If Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A100")) Then` to `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A100")) Is Nothing Then`

**3.** Delete the first `End If`

**4.** Change `If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B100")) Then` to `ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B100")) Is Nothing Then`

**5.** You may want to add a space or a separator after the column name else the result will be concatenated with the column letter. For example, change `MsgBox "column A" & Target.Value` to `MsgBox "Column A : " & Target.Value`

So your code now becomes

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Column A : " & Target.Value
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B100")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Column B : " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your code fixed it thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)